# php mysql results are duplicating first row for each sid

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a mysql query in php that generates distance based on geo coordinates but my query keeps duplicating the data from the first sid row in the table. How do I get my query to generate a result for each row with the called sid's?

Geo Table:

fid | sid | latitude | longitude

887 | 696 | 38.62774 | -90.199514

823 | 696 | 38.63979 | -90.02946

887 | 693 | 38.62774 | -90.199514

823 | 693 | 38.59430 | -90.260372

Query results:

fid | sid | Distance

887 | 696 | 0.05

887 | 696 | 0.05

887 | 693 | 0.05

887 | 693 | 0.05

DESIRED Query results:

fid | sid | Distance

887 | 696 | 0.05

823 | 696 | 3.10

887 | 693 | 0.05

823 | 693 | 12.02

PHP Query:

```
public function ListEntry( &$data ){

    $task = SPRequest::string('task', null );
    if (strtolower($task)!="search.results")
        return ;

    $session = JFactory::getSession();
    $ref_lat = $session->get('mj_rs_ref_lat', null);
    $ref_lng = $session->get('mj_rs_ref_lng', null);
    $ref_loc = $session->get('mj_rs_center_selector', null);
    $ref_dis = $session->get('mj_rs_ref_dist', null);
    if (!$ref_lat OR !$ref_lng)
        return ;

    $km     = $this->_getKm() ;
    $id     = $data['id'] ;
    $db     =& JFactory::getDBO();

    $query = " SELECT GEO.fid, GEO.sid, ";
    $query.= " ({$km}*acos(cos(radians({$ref_lat}))*cos(radians(GEO.latitude))*cos(radians(GEO.longitude)-radians({$ref_lng}))+sin(radians({$ref_lat}))*sin(radians(GEO.latitude)))) AS distance ";
    $query.= " FROM `#__field_geo` AS GEO  ";
    $query.= " WHERE  GEO.sid = {$id} ";
    $query.= " ORDER BY distance ASC ";
    $query.= " LIMIT 1 ";

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $distances = $db->loadAssoc();
    $fidgeo = $distances['fid'];
            $later = $distances['sid'];
    $distance = $distances['distance'];



    }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Nadeem stop adding useless tags!

Comment: Could you give us the sample values for `{$km}`, `{$ref_lat}` and `{$ref_lng}`?

Comment: @Edper {$km} = 3959 (i chose to do the search in miles not km), {$ref_lat} = 38.6270025 and {$ref_lng} = -90.1994042

Comment: I had only 1 result with your provided data.
Can you provide pure sql query for DB? and example $id number.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Distinct keyword in your SQL query

Comment: Yes, I have added Distinct and it doesn't change the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use GROUP BY fid (and HAVING instead WHERE )
it is better of distinct because mysql not read the result table again.

Comment: Could you give me an example of using having instead of where? Thank you for your help

Comment: I try to use your data and the result is not present dublicates.
Can you check again the source data, please?